# ffmpeg: which file formats support stdin usage?

Tags: file, stream, ffmpeg, stdout, stdin

I know ffmpeg is able to read data from `stdin` rather than reading from disk using `ffmpeg -i -`. Is this supported for all file formats? If it is not, is there a list which file formats are supported?

Comment: How do you know that? Is it in the documentation?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You need to run `ffmpeg -protocols` to determine if the `pipe` protocol (the read and write from stdin and stdout) supported in your version of ffmpeg and then `ffmpeg -formats` to see the list of supported formats. In the excerpt below you will see the note on output pipe that it must be seekable for some protocols. For input protocols it has no such restriction.

From `man ffmpeg-protocols`:

> **PROTOCOLS**
>
> Protocols are configured elements in FFmpeg which allow to access
>   resources which  require the use of a particular protocol.
>
> When you configure your FFmpeg build, all the supported protocols are
>   enabled by default. You can list all available ones using the
>   configure option `--list-protocols`.
>
> You can disable all the protocols using the configure option
>   `--disable-protocols`, and selectively enable a protocol using the
>   option `--enable-protocol=PROTOCOL`, or you can disable a particular
>   protocol using the option `--disable-protocol=PROTOCOL`.
>
> The option `-protocols` of the ff* tools will display the list of
>   supported protocols.
>
> A description of the currently available protocols follows. ... pipe
>   UNIX pipe access protocol.
>
> Allow to read and write from UNIX pipes.
>
> The accepted syntax is:
>
> ```
>        pipe:[<number>]
> ```
>
> number is the number corresponding to the file descriptor of the
>   pipe (e.g. 0 for stdin, 1 for stdout, 2 for stderr).  If number is not
>   specified,    by default the stdout file descriptor will be used for
>   writing, stdin for reading.
>
> Note that some formats (typically MOV), require the output protocol
>   to be seekable,    so they will fail with the pipe output protocol.

Comment: Thanks, that perfectly matched my requirements ;)

Comment: In my version of ffmpeg (1.2.1) it's `ffmpeg -protocols`