# How to send opencv video's to ffmpeg

Tags: c++, opencv, ffmpeg

I m trying to send the processed opencv Mat as video to ffmpeg. I m encoding the frame and writing it to std output and then piping it to ffmpeg. Here is my code.

**C++:**

```
if(!cap.isOpened()) {
    cout << "Video not accessible" << endl;
    return -1;
} else {
    cout << "Video is accessible" << endl;
}

while (true) {

    cap >> frame;

    //some processing

    cv::imencode(".jpg", frame, buff);
    for (i = buff.begin(); i != buff.end(); ++i)
        std::cout << *i ;
}
```

My input video resolution is 640x418. I do not alter the video size

After building, I use following command to execute.

`./a.out | ffmpeg -f rawvideo -pix_fmt bgr24 -s 640x418 -r 30 -i - -an -f mpegts udp://0.0.0.0:8182`

and also this

`./a.out | ffmpeg -i pipe:0 -f rawvideo -pix_fmt bgr24 -s 640x418 -r 30 -i - -an -f mpegts udp://0.0.0.0:8182`

However none of this seems to work.

Kindly help.

Comment: Why don't exploit OpenCV VideoWriter class? It uses ffmpeg libraries if they are available

Comment: This may help : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12999674/ffmpeg-which-file-formats-support-stdin-usage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Same question ... same answer...](http://answers.opencv.org/question/94552/how-to-send-opencv-videos-to-ffmpeg/)
I hope this answer will help you.

In this [program](https://github.com/LaurentBerger/wxFilmEcran) I make a screen copy(RGB data) at 20 fps and send image to ffmpeg. i don't use pipe but socket. I use this [command line](https://github.com/LaurentBerger/wxFilmEcran/blob/master/main.cpp#L466) :

```
ffmpeg -f rawvideo -pixel_format rgb24  -video_size 640x480 -i  "tcp://127.0.0.1:2345" -codec:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p Video.mp4
```

to run ffmpeg and then send data to [port 2345 using socket](https://github.com/LaurentBerger/wxFilmEcran/blob/master/main.cpp#L566)

```
sock->Write(b.GetData(), nb);
```

I don't encode frame it is raw data

Comment: Appreciate! I had posted in both communities at the same time!!

Answer (score 4):

Not sure if Jahan is still interested in using pipe, but here's a belated answer:

1. What you write to stdout are images, not videos, so the input format should be `-f jpeg_pipe` and not `rawvideo`.
2. The input source should be `-i pipe:` (colon included)
3. No encoding is needed in the pipe; rather, encoding is specified in ffserver config. For image frames I find that using stream type mjpg is straight forward.
4. A simpler write in opencv can be:
   `fwrite (buff.data(), buff.size(), 1, stdout)`

Comment: Would you mind providing the command line you would use? I've been trying to figure this one out and could not get it to work properly. Thanks!